# HTML 5 form validation for input datetime-local

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying form validation with HTML 5 as described in developer.mozilla.org [Data form validation (developer.mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation). I'm testing it with the Chrome browser. Two questions.

1. I cannot make the form pass with `checkValidity()` when I have an input type of `datetime-local`. The input format of datetime-local is pretty strict (Chrome enforces it to be in certain format) but it just doesn't pass. Why?
2. This `datetime-local` field should NOT be a required field. How do I make it pass when user doesn't specify an input?

Comment: Please show your code in `jsbin.com` or `jsfiddle.net`

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue, please add some code into the question itself. The closest that I came to replicate the issue was by filling only part of the field, leaving half of the field empty (but the validation error was because the field was incomplete, not because it was required)

Comment: I'm actually on JQuery mobile, I don't know if that has to do with it. But OK I'll try it again and put some code on the site and see if I can replicate it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem in chrome 46 & chrome 46 beta, where the **"datetime"** feild ***was*** a required field (users only had two options for input format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD ***and*** PTDHMS, see [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_time_datetime.asp) for value formats and see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime) for compatibility issues.)

so i did not use

```
<input type="datetime" />
```

or:

```
<input type="datetime-local" />
```

I used:

```
<input type="text" />
```

And [Date Js](http://www.datejs.com/) to parse the date / time the user inputted

```
userInput = userInput || 'Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00';
Date.parse(userInput );
```

But you can skip Date.js altogether and use native JavaScript like this: Source ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date))

```
var today = new Date();
var birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17);
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0);
var unixTimestamp = Date.now(); // in milliseconds
```

Also please note that `<input>` elements with `type="datetime-local"` are not supported in Internet Explorer or Firefox (see [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_datetime-local.asp)) but you could try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<head>
<body>
<script>
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "datetime-local");
  document.getElementsByTagName("body").appendChild(input);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Huggie, has my answer helped you? Do you mind sharing if and how you solved the problem?